# How heavy is PrimeFaces on a mobile environment?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to ask how light are pages generated with Primefaces (let's say 4 or 5) in the desktop version (not the mobile one) and whether exists any benchmark to know how usable they  can be in a mobile telephone.

Comment: I think there's no better benchmark than browsing to the components you're interested in into the showcase using your mobile device.

Comment: Actually human feelings are the most imprecise source of information, I would like data, as engineers are used to have. ;)
And I can't have a general idea on behaviour on average phones.

Comment: I know it. But I was literally talking, I wish it was, but the ONLY benchmark you can try seems to be that.

Comment: Anyhow it has been also the first thing I tried. ;)